# A benevolent case for const_cast?

Tags: c++, const-cast

I've read quite a few discussions that const_cast in C++ is considered wrong and dangerous and should not be used for anything other than backward compatibility with C code. And I generally agree.

However recently I came across the following use case and it made me wonder.

I have some model object, owned by a controller, that is generally non-const. I pass it to a view that should not be able to modify the model object, so it would be logical to declare the object as a const parameter when passed to the view. However the view also makes delegate callbacks to the controller, passing the model object as a parameter (e.g. the user clicked this object). The callback parameter also must be const. In the callback method, the controller wants to make a change to the model, but the model is const so it can't do it.

The two solutions:

1. use const_cast in the controller's callback method, since it knows the model object is non-const - but it smells.
2. don't declare the model as const parameter when passed to the view - but then I can't use such a useful tool as the const declaration, which seems very relevant in this case.

Thoughts?

Comment: Why the controller owns the model? And if the view is not read-only, why do you expect to have a const model?

Comment: "Wrong and dangerous" is wrong and dangerous. There are appropriate uses for `const_cast`, and ignoring them because of some dictum is bad coding.

Comment: @vahancho: because the controller is the entry point to the application. It create the model and views and establishes connections between them. The view itself is readonly, but the changes to the model should be made by the controller in response to the view’s events.

Comment: @Pete Becker: that’s why I’m asking in the first place. Don’t want to not use something just because someone said that). Just curious to check colleagues’ opinions to see if I’m overlooking some things and what are others’ practices.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to deal with `const`.

1. Things are `const` if **this code won't directly change them**.
2. Things are `const` if **this code won't change them**.

In this case, the view won't **directly** change the object.  But you want it to **indirectly** change the object.

Under (2), this means the object isn't `const`.  The view can change the object, if indirectly.  It can cause the object to be changed.  Saying it is `const` implies that the views interaction with the object is purely "reading state", not changing the state -- but clicking on the "delete" button of the object and making it delete is a mutating operation.

Under (1), your reference should be `const`, because you aren't yourself modifying it.  Someone else is, under authority granted by their right to do it.

This is one conflict.  And (1) is an acceptable way to use `const`.  But when using (1) you should have **an alternative route** to the object as non-`const`.

We can see this under `vector.erase`.  It (now) takes `const_iterator`s.  Even though those iterators themselves are not permitted to modify the vector, the non-`const`ness of `*this` provides an alternative access path that permits modification.

In your case, the controller owns the object, so should have a non-`const` access path to that object.  That is the path you should use to do non-`const` modification of the object.

When the view makes a delegate callback, it might pass an identifier instead of an object -- or, the controller might extract the identifier from the object somehow, and look it back up in its own list of objects.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about it but object identifiers look like a big overkill. I don’t want to slow down my code with a lookup table just to work around some language peculiarity. Passing the raw object pointer to the view is actually aimed to quickly get the target model back in the controller callback, without an additional lookup.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good case for `const_cast`. If the `view`
accepts the `model` as a `const` then it can be given a truly `const` instance of `model`. It would then be incorrect to try to pass that instance to the controller. If the reference to the `model` given to the `view` can be used to modify the `model`, then it must not be `const`.

Comment: Yes but because I own the entire codebase of the project, I can make it a convention with myself that true const models shall never be used :)

Comment: However, this introduces a new convention you have to remember. And this is one of the worst kinds of convention, one that is opposite to the expectations of anyone who wouldn't know about it. When a function or constructor accepts a `const` reference, you assume that it is safe to pass a `const` instance, an assumption your convention breaks. It does not make this a good case for `const_cast`, it is a very poor use of `const_cast`.

Comment: But without this convention I have to make another convention that I don’t modify the object in the view’s code. Out of these two conventions I think const models are barely practicable, while modifying the model from the view can be tempting.

Comment: @user1548418 But one of those conventions is orders of magnitude more damaging if violated than the other. And you can relatively easily enforce that a view can't modify a non-`const` model while it is very very hard that no `const` instance is given to a `const` reference. One way may be to require a base `view` class which owns the non-const pointer and only provides a `const` getter for derived `view`s. Finally, nobody will doubt that they are being lied to about `const` and are not likely to look that up, while they might look up the constraints when implementing a `view` class.

Comment: My model object is a tree so there is no easy way to write such a getter for a tree node. This is why I am passing the model node in a callback parameter in the first place. And as I said above I don’t want to introduce a lookup table of the nodes only to work around the language peculiarity. The view only communicates with the controller - it receives and sends model data to the controller only. So the convention about non-const models can be encapsulated in the controller, not across the entire project. What a const model is good for in real applications so that I should be worried about it?

Comment: @user1548418 "What should I be worried about?" are famous last words. It isn't because we haven't thought of it that it won't come up. In any case, this is not a good use of `const_cast` because it breaks conventions set by the language in favor of private conventions for little payoff. That's basically all there is to this question.